# Is Netty Suitable For Long Running High TPS Clients

Tags: netty

I've experimenting with a few different libraries for building a server that delivers market data over TCP and Netty.io is one of the candidates. Essentially I have built a small POC and I'm experiencing some performance issues at a high injection rates like 64K TPS. It seems to work fine at 32K TPS but falls off a cliff and effectively grounds to a halt above 64K TPS.

The following time series chart shows the messages IN and OUT of the server at 64K TPS. As you can see at the high injection rate it's all over the place.

[image: 64K TPS]

Here's a similar chart at 32K TPS

[image: 32K TPS]

The code is pretty simple. I consume a request for the client, submit it to a market data service which streams the messages in via an RXJava pipeline I have. The message is encoded into a binary response and sent back to the client over TCP. I'm trying to figure out where I need to start looking. I do know the bottleneck is very much on the encoding side because the number of messages into the server is high to begin with. I do flush the Channel everytime I receive a message, so I'm not sure if that's what's causing it. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
    serverBootstrap
        .group(parentGroup, workerGroup)
        .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
        .localAddress(port)
        .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_SNDBUF, 16777216)
        .childOption(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_WATER_MARK, new WriteBufferWaterMark(16777216,33554432))
        .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                //Build Pipeline to decode, process messages and encode response
                socketChannel.pipeline()
                    .addLast(
                        new FlushConsolidationHandler(1000, true),
                        createMessageFrameBuilder(),
                        new InboundMessageDecoder<>(),
                        new MarketDataReqResponseHandler<>(),
                        new MessageEncoder()
                    );
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should most likely batch up the flushes as `flush()` is expensive. One of the things that you could do is adding the `FlushConsolidationHandler` into the pipeline. This will ensure flushes are merged together when safely possible and so minimise the syscalls.

Comment: Its worth mention that my market data callbacks call `writeAndFlush` on the ChannelPipeline. Is that necessary to send the data to the encoder because it also performs a flush operation on the channel?

Comment: I would need to see your code to better understand what's going on. Also you should add a profiler and see where the time is spend

Comment: I have some tracers in there and most of the time is spent in my outbound encoder. The RXJava callback is receiving messages sometimes at 80k sec but I really only get half that throughput in my outbound encoder when I call write on the ChannelPipeline. So maybe the pipeline is applying backpressure because the encoder cannot encode those messages fast enough. Maybe I need to buffer the messages in the encoder